# Regular expression and hash

Tags: perl

I'm trying to transform strings of the form `201302_1` to `2013-02-09` using a hash. Unfortunately, my knowledge of Perl is rather limited and I haven't gotten it to work yet.

```
BEGIN {
    use strict;
    use warnings;
    use 5.010;

    my %cycle = qw (
      1 '09'  2 '12'  3 '12'  4 '18'  5 '21'
      6 '24'  7 '27'  8 '01'  9 '03'  10 '06'
    );
}

s/(\d{4})(\d{2})_(\d+)$/$1-$2-$cycle{$3}/g
```

It would be great if this script also solved the issue of adding 1 month (increasing `$2`and eventually `$1`) if `$3` is 8, 9 or 10.

I'm running this from the terminal as `perl -p script.pl sample.txt`

Edit: I ended up writing the following based on the answers which seems to work:

```
my %cycle = qw (
  1 09  2 12  3 12  4 18  5 21
  6 24  7 27  8 01  9 03  10 06
);
s{(\d{4})(\d{2})_(\d+)1\.csv$}{
  my @r = (undef, $1, $2, $3);
  if ($3 > 7) {
    $r[2] = sprintf("%02d", $r[2]+1);
  }
  if ($r[2] > 12) {
    $r[2] = "01";
    $r[1] = $r[1] + 1;
  }
  "$r[1]-$r[2]-$cycle{$r[3]}";
}ge;
```

Comment: If you are doing date conversion, you should consider using a proper module for the job, such as [`DateTime`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime) or [`Time::Piece`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Piece).

Comment: I was trying to hash because the hashing to day values is nothing standard. Can this be achieved with `Time::Piece`?

Comment: @user1608941 I don't know. Is that last digit a date, or some other value? You haven't provided any real information about your problem, so its hard to tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solving date math with regexes is usually not a good idea, as it is fairly complicated and filled with edge cases. Use [`Time::Piece`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time%3a%3aPiece) instead:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::Piece;

my %cycle = qw (
  1 09  2 12  3 12  4 18  5 21
  6 24  7 27  8 01  9 03  10 06
);

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    s/_(\d+)$/$cycle{$1}/;
    my $t = Time::Piece->strptime($_, "%Y%m%d");
    $t = $t->add_months(1);
    print $t->strftime("%Y-%m-%d");

}

__DATA__
201302_1
```

Here I have guessed (since you didn't say) that the values in `%cycle` are days, and therefore can be treated like days. So we just replace the digit with the "day" from the hash, then use `strptime` to parse the date, add a month, and then print the date, using `strftime`.

Note that this code assumes the whole string is a date, so you may need to tweak it for use on other kinds of input.

Note also that you can change `<DATA>` to `<>` to use the script as you did before, but without the `-p` switch, i.e.:

```
perl script.pl sample.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

Your strict and warnings are only scoped to the BEGIN block so you aren't seeing the warning that results because %cycle is *also* only scoped to the begin block, and a different (empty) %cycle hash is actually used in the substitution.

Try

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
my %cycle;
BEGIN {
    %cycle = ...
```

Since you plan on adjusting the month and year, I'd avoid the substitution and instead do:

```
my ($year, $month, $cycle) = /\A(\d{4})(\d{2})_(\d+)\z/ or die "bad input: $_\n";
my $day = $cycle{$cycle};
if ( $cycle >= 8 ) {  # or have a second hash that indicates "following month"
```

Comment: +1, but it should perhaps be noted that the entire BEGIN block is unnecessary.

Comment: @TLP: I'm guessing this is run with perl -p or -n and the BEGIN block is to avoid setting %cycle each time.

Comment: Thanks, I simply removed the block and took the hash declaration out.

Answer (score 0):

```
use strict;
use warnings; 
use 5.010;

use DateTime; 

my $input = $ARGV[0];

my %cycle2day = ( 1 => 9,  2 => 12, 3 => 12, 4 =>18, 5 => 21,
                  6 => 24, 7 => 27, 8 => 1, 9 => 3, 10 => 6,
);

my ($year, $month, $cycle) = $input =~ /(\d{4})(\d{2})_(\d+)/;

unless (grep { $cycle == $_ } keys %cycle2day) { 
    die "Unknown cycle $cycle!";
}

my $date = DateTime->new( year => $year,
                          month => $month,
                          day => $cycle2day{$cycle},
                        );

if ( $cycle == 8 or $cycle == 9 or $cycle == 10 ) {
    $date->add(months => 1);
}

say $date->ymd;
```

Outputs:

```
C:\>perl test_cycle.pl 201302_1
2013-02-09

C:\>perl test_cycle.pl 201302_9
2013-03-03
```